# Trying to upload Larav4 on Nginx Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.04 returning 404 page not found

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, laravel-4.2

I am migrating my Laravel4 based app to Digital Ocean .

So I created a folder in

```
/var/www/ideconnect.com/html/
```

and pasted my app code in the folder so now when I do 
`www.ideportal.com/public/` it changes my url to `www.ideportal.com/public/login`

but with a `404 error`

Any Idea whats the problem

Before I had problem of permission denied to write in the error log file which I fixed by run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/ideconnect.com/html/app/storage/
```

But after that I am just getting Page not found 404 error

Thanks